# Running Typesafe Activator from inside Chef cookbook does not work

Tags: bash, scala, chef-infra, typesafe-activator

I have a simple cookbook that uses bash to execute Typesafe's activator, but running "activator stage" action never finishes.

```
bash "Prepare App" do
    user "#{username}"
    group "#{username}"
    cwd "/home/#{username}/my-app"
    code <<-EOH
        activator stage
    EOH
end
```

The recipe above will timeout and never do what is supposed to.
If I run the same command:

```
activator stage
```

from the command line then it works fine. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: What do you mean never finishes? Does it run at all? Is that PATH set correctly?

Comment: I mean the command seems to start, but it just sits there until the Chef "bash" resource times out. Yes the PATH variable is set properly. I omitted it for clarity. I put a comment on the "activator" script, right before the SBT call, so it gets to that point, makes the call then it waits there

Comment: Why using a bash resource and not a simple execute resource ?